# Python pandas - boolean filtering. T/F vs. returning the table

Tags: python, pandas, filter, boolean

I am doing an exercise and have a dataset of school information. I want to filter the data by school year so I have:

```
data['demographics'] = data['demographics'][data['demographics']['schoolyear'] == 20112012]
```

I don't really understand the data['demographics'] at the beginning of the assignment.

If I just have:

```
data['demographics'] = [data['demographics']['schoolyear'] == 20112012]
```

the code returns True or False and not the actual data of the table. How does adding data['demographics'] make Python realize that I want the data returned instead of T/F?

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: df.loc[df['schoolyear']==20112012,'demographics']

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how you are not getting a KeyError, given your exclusive slicing: `['demographics']['schoolyear']`

Answer (score 0):

`data['demographics']['schoolyear'] == 20112012` tells you if they match or not.

So, `[data['demographics']['schoolyear'] == 20112012]` gives you a list of `True` or `False`

So,

```
data['demographics'][data['demographics']['schoolyear'] == 20112012]
```

pulls out the value of `data['demographics']` where you have `True`.

i.e. This gives the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

The first assignment should be throwing a ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.

data['demographics'] this returns only the column 'demographics' of the dataframe, then with this [data['demographics']['schoolyear'] == 20112012] you are filtering the 'demographics' column such that the school year is 20112012.

The error in the statement is that you are trying to assign the filtered data to 
data['demographics'], because the filtered data has less elements than data['demographics'].

I recommend you to assign the filtered data to a new variable like this.

```
filteredData = data['demographics'][data['demographics']['schoolyear'] == 20112012]
```